# ffmpeg output separate channel from an input with multiple channels

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

i run this command to be able to stream a udp live stream to a http live stream that is playable using a mobile application that am building.
its just a stream with audio streams only.

ffmpeg -i udp://@localhost:1111 -map 0:a  http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@localhost:1111':
  Duration: N/A, start: 54616.264622, bitrate: 768 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 1
  service_provider: TLK
    Stream #0:0[0x101]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
  Program 2
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 2
  service_provider: TLK
Stream #0:1[0x111]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
 Program 3
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 3
  service_provider: TLK
Stream #0:2[0x121]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
 Program 4
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 4
  service_provider: TLK
Stream #0:3[0x131]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
  Program 5
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 5
  service_provider: TLK
Stream #0:4[0x141]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
  Program 6
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 6
  service_provider: TLK
Stream #0:5[0x151]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
  Program 7
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 7
  service_provider: TLK
Stream #0:6[0x161]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
 Program 8
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 1
  service_provider: TLK
Stream #0:7[0x171]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
```

i get this output

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=     100kB time=00:00:07.19 bitrate= 113.8kbits/s speed=3.01x
video:0kB audio:84kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB  muxing overhead: 18.358242%
```

i really want a way i can be able to map every input stream to have an output stream that can be accessed separately from the other like maybe if i need the first stream maybe i will just

```
ffplay http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

and if i need the 7th stream i will just

```
ffplay http://localhost:8090/feed7.ffm
```

Please can someone help me crack this issue. FFmpeg dont have complex examples for my current situation.

this is my header information

```
ubuntu@ip-localhost:~$ \ 
ffmpeg -i udp://@localhost:4000 \
  -map 0:a:0     http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm 
  -map 0:a:1 http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm 
  -map 0:a:2 http://localhost:8090/feed3.ffm 
  -map 0:a:3 http://localhost:8090/feed4.ffm 
  -map 0:a:4 http://localhost:8090/feed5.ffm 
  -map 0:a:5 http://localhost:8090/feed6.ffm 
  -map 0:a:6 http://localhost:8090/feed7.ffm 
  -map 0:a:7 http://localhost:8090/feed8.ffm
```

ffmpeg version 3.2.4-1~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg    developers built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-5ubuntu2~16.04.york1) 20170210
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0' -- toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@localhost:1111':
  Duration: N/A, start: 60047.944622, bitrate: 768 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 1
  service_provider: TKL
Stream #0:0[0x101]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
 Program 2
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 2
  service_provider: TKL
Stream #0:1[0x111]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
 Program 3
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 3
  service_provider: TKL
Stream #0:2[0x121]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 4
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 4
  service_provider: TKL
Stream #0:3[0x131]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 5
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 5
  service_provider: TKL
Stream #0:4[0x141]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 6
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 6
  service_provider: TKL
Stream #0:5[0x151]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 7
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 7
  service_provider: TKL
Stream #0:6[0x161]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 8
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service 8
  service_provider: TKL
Stream #0:7[0x171]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 32 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #1, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #1:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #2, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed3.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #2:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #3, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed4.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #3:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #4, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed5.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #4:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #5, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed6.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #5:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #6, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed7.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #6:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #7, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed8.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #7:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #3:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #4:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #5:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #6:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #7:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

thats my full console.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that by running 7 different instances of ffmpeg at the same time as parallel processes; if you're open to that.

Let each instance of ffmpeg demultiplex a single audio stream and output to the respective port.

Would go somewhat like this:

`(ffmpeg -i udp://@localhost:1111 -map 0:a:0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm )
 & (ffmpeg -i udp://@localhost:1111 -map 0:a:1 http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm ) 
 & (ffmpeg -i udp://@localhost:1111 -map 0:a:2 http://localhost:8090/feed3.ffm ) 
 & and so on.`

Wouldn't recommend it though, will eat up your CPU's capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax is `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 {switches} output1 {switches} output2...`, so

```
ffmpeg -i udp://@localhost:1111 -map 0:a:0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm 
                                -map 0:a:1 http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm
                                -map 0:a:2 http://localhost:8090/feed3.ffm
                                ...
```

Comment: i have tried and it copies the first stream to all others
    Stream mapping:Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #3:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #4:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #5:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #6:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #7:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Comment: Show the full console output.

Comment: this is the link to the short sample. it has all the 8 stream channels. Please download it and try to simulate my situation. http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B12_TxWYu6LzMlBsTDVMN2RjZ1E