# Demultiplex UDP live stream to multiple single live stream outputs using FFMPEG & FFSERVE

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

i have a problem with ffmpeg. i have an input live stream that has 8 inputs and i want to use ffmpeg to convert it from udp live steram to tcp livestream and then extract each of the 8 input stream differently.

i have been reading about the ffmpeg documentation at they havent provided a clear way of solving my problem.

am running

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4-1~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-5ubuntu2~16.04.york1) 20170210 configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared libavutil 55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101 libavcodec 57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101 libavformat 57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101 libavdevice 57. 1.100 / 57. 1.100 libavfilter 6. 65.100 / 6. 65.100 libavresample 3. 1. 0 / 3. 1. 0 libswscale 4. 2.100 / 4. 2.100 libswresample 2. 3.100 / 2. 3.100 libpostproc 54. 1.100 / 54. 1.100
```

am running this command to help me split my input into multiple output that can be accessed differently.

```
ffmpeg \
-i udp://@localhost:4000 -loglevel debug \
-map 0:0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm \
-map 0:1 http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm \
-map 0:2 http://localhost:8090/feed3.ffm \
-map 0:3 http://localhost:8090/feed4.ffm \
-map 0:4 http://localhost:8090/feed5.ffm \
-map 0:5 http://localhost:8090/feed6.ffm \
-map 0:6 http://localhost:8090/feed7.ffm \
-map 0:7 http://localhost:8090/feed8.ffm
```

this is my full output

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-57:~$ ffmpeg -i udp://@localhost:4000  -map 0:0  http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm  -map 0:1 http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm  -map 0:2 http://localhost:8090/feed3.ffm  -map 0:3 http://localhost:8090/feed4.ffm  -map 0:4 http://localhost:8090/feed5.ffm  -map 0:5 http://localhost:8090/feed6.ffm  -map 0:6 http://localhost:8090/feed7.ffm  -map 0:7 http://localhost:8090/feed8.ffm

ffmpeg version 3.2.4-1~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-5ubuntu2~16.04.york1) 20170210 configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101 libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101 libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101 libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100 libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100 libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0 libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100 libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100 libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100


Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@localhost:4000':
 Duration: N/A, start: 14580.980000, bitrate: 768 kb/s
 Program 1
Metadata:
  service_name    : STREAM1
  service_provider: RAL
Stream #0:0[0x101]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 2
Metadata:
  service_name    : STREAM2
  service_provider: RAL
Stream #0:1[0x111]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 3
Metadata:
  service_name    : STREAM3
  service_provider: RAL
Stream #0:2[0x121]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
  Program 4
  Metadata:
  service_name    : STREAM4
  service_provider: RAL
Stream #0:3[0x131]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 5
Metadata:
  service_name    : STREAM5
  service_provider: RAL
Stream #0:4[0x141]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 6
Metadata:
  service_name    : STREAM6
  service_provider: RAL
Stream #0:5[0x151]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 7
Metadata:
  service_name    : STREAM7
  service_provider: RAL
Stream #0:6[0x161]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Program 8
Metadata:
  service_name    : STREAM8
  service_provider: RAL
Stream #0:7[0x171]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #1, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #1:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #2, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed3.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #2:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #3, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed4.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #3:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #4, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed5.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #4:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #5, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed6.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #5:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #6, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed7.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #6:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Output #7, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed8.ffm':
Metadata:
creation_time   : now
encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
Stream #7:0: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mp2
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #3:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #4:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #5:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #6:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #7:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=      72kB time=00:00:07.66 bitrate=  76.9kbits/s speed=2.68x
video:0kB audio:480kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

these are my live feeds.

```
<Feed feed2.ffm>


File /tmp/feed2.ffm
FileMaxSize 64M

ACL allow 127.0.0.1

</Feed>

<Feed feed3.ffm>


  File /tmp/feed3.ffm
  FileMaxSize 64M

  ACL allow 127.0.0.1

</Feed>


<Feed feed4.ffm>


  File /tmp/feed4.ffm
  FileMaxSize 64M

  ACL allow 127.0.0.1

</Feed>
```

these are my stream

## MP3 audio

```
<Stream radio1.mp3>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format mp2
#AudioCodec mp3
AudioBitRate 64
AudioChannels 2
AudioSampleRate 44100
NoVideo
</Stream>

<Stream radio2.mp3>
Feed feed2.ffm
Format mp2
#AudioCodec mp3
AudioBitRate 64
AudioChannels 2
AudioSampleRate 44100
NoVideo
</Stream>

<Stream radio3.mp3>
Feed feed3.ffm
Format mp2
#AudioCodec mp3
AudioBitRate 64
AudioChannels 2
AudioSampleRate 44100
NoVideo
</Stream>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ffmpeg output separate channel from an input with multiple channels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248458/ffmpeg-output-separate-channel-from-an-input-with-multiple-channels)

Comment: Upload a short sample.

Comment: this is the link to the short sample. it has all the 8 stream channels.   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B12_TxWYu6LzMlBsTDVMN2RjZ1E

Comment: The mapping works here: `Stream #0:4 -> #0:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp2 (native))`. Likely something to do with ffserver config. Try the mailing list.

Comment: i have realised that if i run the command but i just save it a file , it works fine, `code` ffmpeg \
    -i udp://@localhost:4000 -loglevel debug \
    -map 0:0 /tmp/stream0.mp2 \
    -map 0:1 /tmp/stream1.mp2 \

but when i try so stream output it just doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -window_size qcif -f sdl "SDL output"
```

This works for me on Windows.